# Spring MVC returning 405 when trying to render JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've recently been trying to implement a simple healthcheck service for our Spring project using Spring MVC with a JSP webpage. This is my first time working with Spring MVC and I've been working through [this Spring MVC tutorial.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) The problem seems to be that when it is trying to render my page, it returns a 405 and I don't understand why. If someone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Right now I have a servlet and mapping setup as follows in my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>health</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>health</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/health</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And I have my `health-servlet.xml` configured as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />

<import resource="classpath*:applicationContext.xml" />

<bean id="viewResolver"         
             class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/health/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

I also have a simple controller setup:

```
@Controller
public class HealthcheckEndpoint {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/health", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String checkHealth(ModelMap mav) {
        // Some business logic
        return "healthcheck";
    }
}
```

Also, I do have a `.jsp` page setup in `WEB-INF/health/healthcheck.jsp`.

I have turned on `org.springframework.web` logging and these are the last 2 lines before I get the 405 response:

```
[2012-01-31 12:52:04,770] DEBUG - org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(236) | Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/health/healthcheck.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'healthcheck'
[2012-01-31 12:52:04,780] DEBUG - org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(674) | Successfully completed request
```

**Update**

Also defined in my `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext-resources.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And in my `applicationContext-resources.xml` I do have the line `context:annotation-config`.

*Note:* This health servlet is an addition to our already existing service. Hence, now there are 2 `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` servlets defined in our `web.xml`. I don't know if this is a problem or not, but it seems to work because I can debug into both endpoints.

Comment: maybe you can change '/health' to '/health/*' in your web.xml under servlet-mapping tag. Also try network capturing with firebug or any other explorer tool to see if you try any post method.

Comment: @HRgiger Changing to servlet-mapping had the same result. Also, when I monitored the network with Firebug, it said there was only 1 request which was my GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite what my note says, one of the other servlets was eating the output by this url request. I have imported this [URL re-write tool](http://www.tuckey.org/) and everything is now working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

A `405` "Method not allowed" means the HTTP method (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) used on the resource (e.g. `/health`) is not supported by the server. You've clearly indicated that `GET` is supported (in your controller) so my guess is you are hitting your URL with the wrong HTTP method (`POST` perhaps?).

---

EDIT: So you are doing a `GET`.

On further examination of your configuration I believe you need a `<context:annotation-config/>` line that tells Spring to process annotations (like on your controller) allowing it to know about your `GET` support. Perhaps try that?

Comment: The way I am trying to access this is by putting a URL into my browser: http://localhost:8080/myapp/health

Comment: OK. That's not it then. I've added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer to clarify that we do have that line.

Answer (score 1):

According to your configuration, behavior description and log file, I would guess that the problem is not that jsp in first place. I would guess that your JSP (HTML) loads some other resources that trigger the 405.